# How to make hyperref aware of Firefox's internal protocols for extensions?

Tags: hyperref, links, zotero

I'd like to create an hyperlink in a `.pdf` file that opens Firefox at the Zotero pane, the "URL" of which being `chrome://zotero/content/tab.xul`: instead of `http` or `ftp`, here the protocol used is `chrome`, one of Firefox's internal protocols for extensions.

Unfortunately, nothing happens when one clicks on the link produced by the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{chrome://zotero/content/tab.xul}{Zotero}%
\end{document}
```

Hence my question, how to make `hyperref` aware of Firefox's internal protocols for extensions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following produces a more readable PDF file:

```
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{chrome://zotero/content/tab.xul}{Zotero}%
\end{document}
```

Page streams are still compressed, but the link is stored in an uncompressed
annotation object in the PDF file. The file can be inspected by a text viewer (or editor):

```pdf
23 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 1]
/Rect [147.716 656.239 177.964 665.039]
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(chrome://zotero/content/tab.xul)>>
>>
endobj
```

As can be seen, the URL is unchanged. Thus the problem is rather the PDF viewer, who does not know how to handle the protocol `chrome`, which program it should start.

Comment: None of the PDF viewer I tried on Linux (including `acroread`) does know how to handle the `chrome` protocol.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé My test URL was  `zotero://attachment/4/`, which was successful in `xpdf`.

Comment: Indeed, this opens a new tab in Firefox but, at `zotero://attachment/4/`, I'm nowhere :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The exact URL depends on the available data.

Comment: AFAICS, `chrome://zotero/content/tab.xul` is the generic URL for the Zotero pane in Firefox.